# JNA passing pointer ByReference

Tags: pointers, pass-by-reference, jna

I'm calling a function from a DLL, using JNA, which needs an unsigned *short input argument

```
unsigned void my_function(unsigned long handle, unsigned short * serial);
```

I tried to pass serial as a `ShortByReference`

```
my_function(long handle, ShortByReference serial);
```

When I use it, `my_function` does the work, but serial is not retrieved (it stays at its initialisation value).

I also tried

```
my_function(long handle, short[] serial);
```

but it does the same.

How could i do it correctly?

Thanks, Arn0.

Comment: Are you certain your native code is actually updating the value?

Comment: Indeed, I am, i have used this library with other programming languages(VBA, and also with MATLAB), and it did return the correct value. To specify my problem, the function take the handle value, does some work, and after that should fills in the value pointed by serial.

Comment: Make sure your `handle` argument uses `NativeLong` (or `int` on windows) and that your calling convention is correct.

Comment: I am sure of that too. The library have other functions wich take handle, and those functions work fine. The only difference I see with this one is that it takes a pointer input argument. I'm wondering if there could be a problem with the library, but it's stucked only when used with java.

Comment: Your question uses Java `long` for `unsigned long`, which is incorrect (64 bits vs. indeterminate type size).

Comment: The problem was there! I work on a 32bits version of windows, so unsigned long refer to a 32bits variable. I don't understand why my other functions worked with that issue, but i'll figure it out. Tank you! I guess I have to set my question answered now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NativeLong` (not `long`) to represent native `unsigned long`.